# Connect Android studio to Oracle

Tags: android, oracle, android-studio

I want to connect to Oracle,
After setting

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

I am reciving the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I did copy `ojdbc14.jar` to into my project in the libs directory, after executing `Add as Library`, I wrote in `build.grades` "`compile files ('libs/ojdbc14.jar')`"
After that I exeecuted in the cmd line "`gradlew clean`"

Why is the project still not working?

Answer (score 0):

After making changes to the `build.gradle` file, if you still have the project open in Android Studio, you need to click on the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button in the toolbar to make it pick up the changes.

Comment: Click on the "Sync Project with Gradle Files", run project and error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException